# Is it possible to fill a progress bar based on the amount of time a thread has been sleeping?

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, sleep, android-progressbar

I am trying to determine a way to create a progress bar that will gradually fill based on the amount of time a thread sleeps. I have tried this with progressbar.setProgress, but I cant seem to figure out a way to gradually update the progress bar based on how long this thread will sleep. At the moment the bar does nothing.

Any assistance in finding a solution is greatly appreciated. If there is a better way to perform the tasks to take advantage of using the progress bar please let me know.

```
private void autoruncheck
  if (Autorun){
  (new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("thread");

        mprogressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.Id.progressbar1);
        mprogressbar.setMax(100);
        mprogressbar.setProgress(0);
            while(Autorun)
                try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                       //do work
                       mprogressbar.setProgress(100);
                       UpdateUI();;
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
    }
})).start();
```

}

Comment: ... and the point is? ... first of all do not touch ui elements in another thread

Comment: To be more specific, when launched im checking for if the autorun condition has been met and if so loop an action. Every time the action is performed it needs to be updated in the UI. Admittedly I am very new to this, so if this is not the correct way of doing a loop that calls back to the UI thread please let me know. In addition the action should not be instant, which is the reason for the sleep, but I would like to show how long it will be until said action is completed. So I wanted to use a progress bar for this.

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, use Thread.sleep(). Implement your own busy loop if needed, that allows you to update the UI too.

Comment: If what you want is a timed splash screen or a fake progress bar, you should be looking at handlers and postDelayedMessage

Comment: Ill try to find some examples of handlers/postDelayedMessage and get it working instead of a Thread.sleep then. I assume the fake progress bar would work, I could just match it with the wait for the task and essentially get the desired result.